# Windows phone 8 webbrowser Control stays blank on dropbox

Tags: windows-phone-8, browser, dropbox

I try to create an WP8 app with a dropbox connection, but I get problems in the authentification process. From the library I downloaded, I get an URL which leads to the loginscreen to authenticate my app. This works fine, but after I entered the logindata, the screen stays blank. This is the behavior in the webbrowser control.
If I open the same URL in Internet Explorer, it works fine, but this is no alternative solution, because my app freezes in the background, so I have to solve it by `WebBrowser` control.

The only code in my webview class is this:

```
webview.Source = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
```

webview is the `WebBowser` control and `url` contains the url to the login page.

Does anyone know a possible solution for this? Do I have to do something to change the page after the user pressed the login button or should this work automatically? Or is it possible to observe Internet Explorer with my app so I can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to this problem.
I had to set the property IsScriptEnabled to true to enable JavaScript.
This value is false on default.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462081(v=vs.105).aspx